# Is Canon 16-35/4 IS better than 16-35/2.8 II at f/4?

Tags: lens, canon

I have had a 16-35/2.8 II for almost a year, but it broke and I might be in the market to replace it. Last week I saw that Canon had released a new lens in this range, but with f/4 and IS.

Is Canon 16-35/4 IS better than 16-35/2.8 II at f/4? Better as in sharper etc.

What I've read suggests it.

Comment: The manufacturer MTFs seem to indicate this, but I couldn't find any third party testing to confirm it yet.  It wouldn't be particularly surprising though since it is a much newer lens and still in a relatively similar price range.

Comment: digital picture has only reviewed the theoretical performance and they look forward to testing if the MTF is right.

Comment: It is available on [this link](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EF-16-35mm-f-4-L-IS-USM-Lens.aspx), bottom of page. You can compare the two by rolling over it. If the chart is true, the 16-35/f4 is a very good lens.

Comment: As this lens is not yet released, I believe this question should be closed. Other than the existing MTF charts no one is going to have insider info here.

Comment: "Better" always depends on your use case. If you need the aperture/speed to freeze moving subjects there is no substitute for f/2.8 vs. f/4. If your subjects are stationary then f/4 + IS might allow you to shoot handheld at the longer Tv needed and get better results. If you are shooting from a tripod the IS becomes irrelevant but the shallower DoF of the f/2.8 lens may allow you to get shots you want that the f/4 lens would not.

Comment: For my money unless I really need the IS to shoot slow shutter speeds handheld, the EF 17-40mm f/4 L is the most bang for the buck. It is also pretty good optically and significantly smaller/lighter/cheaper than either of the 16-35mm choices.

Comment: @MichaelClark According the the MFTs this new lens is sharper than both 16-35/2.8 and 17-40/4.0. But I guess those are measured wide open.

Comment: I don't believe I said any lens was sharper. But the 17-40 is plenty sharp and probably sharp enough for any use that doesn't involve billboards or full page glossy magazine ads. MFT charts are only part of the story, especially when many recent MFT charts are generated by computer simulations of the design, not actual measurements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have owned the first 16-35 f2,8, the successor 16-35 f2.8 II and the 17-40 f4, and now the 16-35 f4.  The new lens is much better in the corners and is really sharp overall.  I sold the earlier wide angle zooms and even a 14mm f2.8 prime because the edges were unusable even stopped down.  I had to crop frequently to eliminate the smeared parts. I finally got a 17mm TS/E and it did the job but is huge and does not autofocus.  The new lens does not have these problems.  In my opinion, the new lens is the first Canon wide angle zoom worthy of the great Canon bodies.

Answer (score 0):

I too think the new canon 16-35 f4 is has better image quality compared to the older version. But this depends for what you are using it, if you really need that extra stop of light.